# RegEx to extract first set of digits only

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I am trying to extract the 1st group of digits from this expression "CSTAR ADJ REF # A-3080101078AZ Keying error Deposit $ 938,710.33 on 05/20/2011 item keying". That is, i want to get only "3080101078" as result in an adjacent cell.

I have tried using this:

```
Function CleanString(strIn As String) As String
    Dim objRegex
    Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With objRegex
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "[^0-9\s]"
        CleanString= Trim(.Replace(strIn, vbNullString))
    End With
End Function
```

This is giving "3080101078     93871033  05202011". How can i get the first group of number only (3080101078) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Function CleanString(strIn As String) As String
    Dim objRegex As Object
    Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With objRegex
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "\d+"
        CleanString = .Execute(strIn)(0)
    End With
End Function
```

`\d+` = any digit, one or more

`.Execute(strIn)` executes the regex against the input, returnining a `MatchCollection`

`.Execute(strIn)(0)` returns the first item in the match collection