# RegEx - VBA Finding splitting cell with two Uppercase

Tags: regex, string, vba, split

I am looking to split a cell after the first instance of a word with multiple caps.

**Example 1:**

**Input1:** Floor 4 InformatiqueNoosavilleSep

Desired **Output1:** NoosavilleSep

**Pattern:** The split should occurs at the second instance of uppercase in the last word. "InformatiqueNoosavilleSep"

**Example 2:**

**Input:** Floor 13 InformatiqueSurfers ParadiseSep

**Output:** Surfers ParadiseSep

**Pattern:** The split shouldn't occurs at the last word but on "InformatiqueSurfers" instead.

**The problem:** The pattern to find where to split the word differs from a cell to another.

**What we know:**

1: If the last word contains three uppercase letter it's always at this word that we want to split the string.**Example1**

2: If the last word contains only two uppercase letter "ParadiseSep" we have to split the string on the the word before it. **Example2**

I found this code which allow to split string with caps lock and add a spaces.

```
Dim objRegex As Object
Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With objRegex
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "([a-z])([A-Z])"
    SplitCaps = .Replace(strIn, "$1 $2")
End With
End Function
```

As I am trying to learn VBA this Regex is getting a bit out of my realm.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: You are on the right track, replace with `vbNull` and then split the string at `vbNull`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35254567/3832970).

Comment: Try `.Pattern = "(?:[A-Z][a-z]+)((?:[A-Z][a-z]* ?)+)"` and `strIn = .Execute(strIn)(0).SubMatches(0)`

Comment: Thanks. Works well for the case where the last word have two uppercase. But not when the last word have three of them.