# How to split a string in VBA to array by Split function delimited by Regular Expression

Tags: regex, excel, vba, excel-addins

I am writing an Excel Add In to read a text file, extract values and write them to an Excel file. I need to split a line, delimited by **one or more white spaces** and store it in the form of array, from which I want to extract desired values.

I am trying to implement something like this:

```
arrStr = Split(line, "/^\s*/")
```

But the editor is throwing an error while compiling.

How can I do what I want?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28107005/splitting-string-in-vba-using-regex

Comment: Split doesn't do that.  You'll need to find another way.  Why the arbitrary "one line" requirement?   Reflex could dot it in a few lines

Comment: _"...edit is throwing an error while compiling"_ Please consider being more specific. The error number and description is valuable.

Comment: It is throwing an error because you haven't enclosed your string with quotes.

Comment: Also, the regex for a whitespace is a lower-case `s` after a backwards slash, so: `\s` ... When you use an uppercase `\S` that means "Every possible character **other than** a whitespace"

Comment: @K.Davis Sorry. Typing error. It is editor

Comment: @CatCat, K.Davis Thanks. Let me try

Comment: You're still not going to be able to do that with the `Split()` function. Question, is this truly VBScript as you've tagged? Or are you actually using [tag:vba] "Visual Basic for Applications"? VBA is what you get when you press `Alt + F11` inside Excel - not VBScript.

Comment: @K.Davis Yes. I am actually using VBA in Excel by pressing Alt+F11.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - could you please [edit] your question and update the correct tag so you reach the correct audience?

Comment: Now I have written code as `arrStr = Split(line, "/^\s*/")`. Now it is not throwing error. But it is returning whole line as only element of the array `arrStr`.

Comment: `split` **doesn't** do RegEx.

Comment: @CatCat Thanks. I need to use `Mid` function then. By the way, is my code treating the Regex as plain string?

Comment: **Yes** it is doing that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are looking for the Regular Expressions route, then you could do something like this:

```
Dim line As String, arrStr, i As Long
line = "This is a  test"

With New RegExp
    .Pattern = "\S+"
    .Global = True
    If .test(line) Then
        With .Execute(line)
            ReDim arrStr(.Count - 1)
            For i = 0 To .Count - 1
                arrStr(i) = .Item(i)
            Next
        End With
    End If
End With
```

> **IMPORTANT:** You will need to create a reference to:
>   `Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5` in Tools > References
>   Otherwise, you can see **Late Binding** below

Your original implementation of your original pattern `\^S*\$` had some issues:

- `S*` was actually matching a literal uppercase S, not the whitespace character you were looking for - because it was not escaped.

  - Even if it was escaped, you would have matched every string that you used because of your quantifier: `*` means to match **zero** or more of `\S`. You were probably looking for the `+` quantifier (**one** or more of).
  - You were good for making it greedy (not using `*?`) since you were wanting to consume as much as possible.

The Pattern I used: `(\S+)` is placed in a *capturing group* `(...)` that will capture all cases of `\S+` (all characters that are NOT a white space, `+` one or more times.

I also used the `.Global` so you will continue matching after the first match.

Once you have captured all your words, you can then loop through the match collection and place them into an array.

---

## Late Binding:

```
Dim line As String, arrStr, i As Long
line = "This is a  test"

With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    .Pattern = "\S+"
    .Global = True
    If .test(line) Then
        With .Execute(line)
            ReDim arrStr(.Count - 1)
            For i = 0 To .Count - 1
                arrStr(i) = .Item(i)
            Next
        End With
    End If
End With
```

---

#### Miscellaneous Notes

I would have advised just to use `Split()`, but you stated that there were cases where more than one consecutive space may have been an issue. If this wasn't the case, you wouldn't need regex at all, something like:

```
arrStr = Split(line)
```

Would have split on every occurance of a space

Comment: @kush.impetus If you remove the redundant capturing group it will be cleaner: `.Pattern = "\S+"` and `arrStr(i) = .Item(i)` (there won't be any need to access `Submatches(0)`)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for pointing that out - that was leftover as part of a different route I was taking. I corrected it :)

Comment: @K.Davis. Thanks. Your code has made my task lot easier.