# How to split by comma followed by 8(n) digit numeric value? (Excel VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to split string similar to

```
12345678 text, text, text,87654321 text, text, text
```

by comma followed by 8 digit number, so the result should look like: `"12345678 text, text, text"` and `"87654321 text, text, text"`.

Each of the separated strings I want to insert in array, so the code I came up with is:

```vb
Dim arrCombined() As String
arrCombined() = Split(.Cells(i, j).Value2, ",########")
```

However this doesn't work as I expected and the result is only one element in the array, which holds the whole string not separated.

Any ideas? :)

Comment: No, `Split` does not support formatting patterns and does not recognize `#` as a placeholder for digits. And if it were, it would return `"12345678 text, text, text"` and `"text, text, text"`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Splitting String in VBA using RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28107005/11683)

Comment: Try reading the help page on split. All you need is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Split` does not accept placeholders or patterns.  One possibility is to `Split` on the *comma*, and then join the other portions back on, creating a new entry when the text starts with 8 digits.  Roughly, something along these lines:

```
Function SplitCommaEightDigits(Value as String) AS Variant
    Dim arrWorking AS Variant, arrOutput() AS Variant
    Dim lCurrent AS Long, lCount AS Long

    Redim arrOutput(0 to 0)

    arrWorking = Split(Value, ",")
    lCount = -1

    For lCurrent = lBound(arrWorking) to uBound(arrWorking)
        If IsNumeric(Left(arrWorking(lCurrent),8)) Then
            'Create new record
            lCount = lCount+1
            Redim Preserve arrOutput(0 to lCount)
            arrOutput(lCount) = arrWorking(lCurrent)
        Else
            'Add to current record
            arrOutput(lCount) = arrOutput(lCount) & _
                IIF(Len(arrOutput(lCount))>0,",","") & arrWorking(lCurrent)
        End If
    Next lCurrent

    SplitCommaEightDigits = arrOutput
End Function
```

Comment: Straight ahead solution! FYI Might be interested in my approach coming close to OP @Chronocidal +:)

Answer (score 3):

Try the next function, please:

```
Function strSplit(x As String) As Variant
  Dim arr(1) As Variant
  arr(0) = Replace(Split(Replace(x, ", ", "|"), ",")(0), "|", ", ")
  arr(1) = Replace(Split(Replace(x, ", ", "|"), ",")(1), "|", ", ")
  strSplit = arr
End Function
```

It can be called in this way:

```
Sub teststrSplit()
  Dim x As String, arr As Variant
  x = "12345678 text, text, text,87654321 text, text, text"
  arr = strSplit(x)
  Debug.Print "String 1: " & arr(0)
  Debug.Print "String 2: " & arr(1)
End Sub
```

**Edited:**

The variant able to return all occurrences:

```
Function strSplitX(x As String) As Variant
  Dim arr As Variant, El As Variant
  arr = Split(Replace(x, ", ", "|"), ",")
  For Each El In arr
    El = Replace(El, "|", ", ")
  Next
  strSplitX = arr
End Function
```

It can be tested/called in this way:

```
Sub teststrSplitX()
  Dim x As String, arr As Variant, i As Long
  x = "12345678 text, text, text,87654321 text, text, text, text,89654323 text, text, text"
  arr = strSplitX(x)
  For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
    Debug.Print "String " & i + 1 & ": " & arr(i)
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The string I provided in the exapmle contains only two sub-strings and your code could be a solution for it, but since in the real application sub-strings are not fixed number, Chronocidal answer is better. Anyway thanks for you answer.

Comment: As far as I understood first,too OP wanted to split into two tokens; nevertheless like the **slim** function +:)

Comment: @HYs: My above function can easily be adapted to deal with as many such strings exist. You did not say anything about many occurrences...

Comment: @T.M.: It is not very complicated to be transformed in what he said now. But, if he prefers a iteration solution, this keeps of the people taste... :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try something like:

```
Sub Test()

Dim str As String: str = "12345678 text, text, text,87654321 text, text, text"
Dim arrCombined() As String

With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    .Pattern = ",(?=\d{8}\D)"
    .Global = True
    arrCombined = Split(.Replace(str, "|"), "|")
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: A solid answer completing above solutions by RegEx +:)

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun:

```
Sub TestSplit()
Dim s$: s = "12345678 text, text, text,87654321 text, text, text"
Dim arrCombined() As String
'1) call sub procedure (passing array reference and string)
    SplitComma8D arrCombined, s
'2) check result in VB Editor's Immediate window
    Debug.Print Join(arrCombined, "|")  ' 12345678 text, text, text|87654321 text, text, text
End Sub
```

**Sub procedure called by above example call**

```
Sub SplitComma8D(arr, s As String)
'a) classical split
    arr = Split(s, ",")
'b) check for ",##########" condition via Like
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        If arr(i) Like String(8, "#") & "*" Then
            arr(i) = "#" & arr(i)             
        End If
Next
'c) return result split
    'arr = Split(Join(arr, ","), ",#", 2)    ' split in two pieces
    arr = Split(Join(arr, ","), ",#")        ' split in two or more pieces
End Sub
```